# Conditional Formatting on an MS Access form

Tags: forms, ms-access, conditional-formatting

Is there way to use conditional formatting (similar to excel) to a text box in an ms access form? The user will enter a number in the text box. If the number is between 0-25 is red, if its from 26-50 its yellow, if its from 51-75 than green and 76-100 blue.

How can this be done in MS Access?
?

Comment: With the form in Design View, right-click the text box and choose Conditional Formatting.  Make Condition 1 Field Value Is between 0 and 25, and choose red from the Font/Fore Color dropdown.  Click the "Add >>" button to add another condition (Condition 2) ... between 26 and 50, yellow.  Repeat for the remaining conditions.

Comment: Hans, you shoup put that as an answer and let JT accept it.  Reduce the 'Unanswered' list.  =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note as @Nexus mentioned below, the `FormatConditions` collection will only accept 3 conditions.  But you were aiming for 4 conditions.  Unless you can consolidate those into only 3, you won't be able to use Access' conditional formatting feature for this.

With the form in Design View, right-click the text box and choose *"Conditional Formatting ..."* from the context menu.

Select *"Field Value Is"* from the drop-down under *Condition 1*, *"between"* in the second drop-down, and enter your start (0) and end (25) range values in the next 2 boxes.  Choose red from the *Font/Fore Color* drop-down.

Click the *"Add >>"* button to add another condition (*Condition 2*).  Set the values for that condition: 26; 50; and yellow.

Repeat for the remaining conditions.

Here's a screen capture of your first 2 conditions applied to a text box.  (I chose light grey for the background color so the foreground colors would be more distinct in format preview area.)

[image]

Comment: i don't think this solve the problem as MS Access conditional format only allows up to 3 conditions while the question asked for 4 conditions

Comment: could you not use 3 conditions and the 4th be the default?

Comment: Yes, sort of.  The "default" would also apply when the text box contains -50 or 300.  If that's acceptable, you're good to go.  :-)